# Right way to create custom pgsql types in django

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-syncdb, django-evolution

What is the right way to create custom pgsql types for django application so that each time database is created with syncdb, all custom types are created prior to creating any tables (so that tables can use this type)?

I also use django-evolution, but that's not an appropriate solution — it runs after syncdb. I can imagine doing a workaround like defining models with standard field types and then creating types and altering column types in evolutions, but that's definitely not nice and sort of obscure...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do this in Django.  As you probably know, there's a `post_syncdb` signal but no signal for `pre_syncdb`.

So I think there's only two options: hacking `pre_syncdb` signal into Django or use an automation tool like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/).

Hacking your own `pre_syncdb` signal, even if it's the right way to do this, probably won't be simple and you have to maintain the patch each new Django release.

On the other hand, not only is an automation tool like Fabric simple but it provides other benefits to your project.

As an example, a portion of my Fabfile looks like:

```
def createdb():
    "Create a clean database"
    run('createdb --encoding=UNICODE $(db_name) -O $(db_owner) -U $(db_owner)')
    run('python manage.py syncdb --noinput')
```

Add something like this just before the syncdb:

```
run('psql -U $(db_owner) $(db_name) < app/sql/custom_types.sql')
```

and you should be good to go by just typing:

```
$ fab createdb
```

or:

```
$ fab cluster createdb
```

to run the command on all the machines listed in your environment called `cluster`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about hacking pre_syncdb — and I can actually submit it as patch. I am also using my own git repo for django so I have no problem maintaining my set of patches until they are in the mainstream...
I just thought may be there is any other way, but apparently there is none.. pre_syncdb looks quite naturally, so I'll probably go for it.

Comment: Well I'm not a Django dev so my answer can't be authoritative.  There might be good reasons why they don't have a pre_syncdb signal and there might be another way to do it.  I'd ask the question on django-dev mailing list before doing any coding.